# Webview Send Post Json

Tags: java, android, webview

I have String Json:

```
String data = "param:"+"{\"dataFile\": \n" +
                "{\"user\": \"asdasdasd\", \n" +
                "\"pwd\":\"vasdadsda\", \"email\": \"vasdasdasd@gg.com\" \n" +
                "}\n" +
                "}";
```

Then try to send post to API with webview JSON like this:

```
myWebView.postUrl("url.com", data.getBytes());
```

from API the json process with "param" key then get the value, but the json get from API is null, any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I post my data like this. You may also try with this.

```
String postData = null;
            try {

                postData = "email=" + URLEncoder.encode(MyApp.getSharedPrefString(StaticData.EMAIL), "UTF-8") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(MyApp.getSharedPrefString(StaticData.PASSWORD), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            webview.postUrl("url.com",postData.getBytes());
```